# HttpOpenRequest and Accept header

Tags: windows, http, winapi, wininet

`HttpOpenRequest` takes an http accept header in a very weird format. Is it okay to ignore that parameter and add a normal accept header with `HttpAddRequestHeaders` later ?

```
  hfile = HttpOpenRequest(hLastConnection, 'GET', '/path',  NULL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD | INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION, 0);
  HttpAddRequestHeaders(hfile,'Accept: foobar', 14, HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_REPLACE or HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);
```

It does work (in WINE), but seems undocumented.

Similarly, how is the situation for content-type and referer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing *weird* about how `HttpOpenRequest()` accepts the `Accept` values. It is just an array of null-terminated strings. The `Accept` header allows for multiple types.  `HttpOpenRequest()` will concatenate the values and format the `Accept` header for you.  With `HttpAddRequestHeaders()`, you have to do that manually. But whether you use `HttpOpenRequest()` or `HttpAddRequestHeaders()` makes no difference, as the `Accept` header does not affect the client at all, so it does not matter how you get it into the request. It only affects the server when it is preparing the response.

Same with `Referer`, it does not affect the client, only the server, so add it to the request however you want. Though `HttpOpenRequest()` has a nice simple parameter for the `Referer` value so you should use it.

`Content-Type`, on the other hand, can only be set with `HttpAddRequestHeaders()`.  But it doesn't make sense to specify a `Content-Type` for a `GET` request since there is no payload in the request. `Content-Type` only applies to requests with payloads, like `POST` and `PUT`.

Comment: Well, I already have a list of all formatted headers. It would be weird to search `accept` in that list and unsplit it, just to have `HttpOpenRequest` join it together again.   The example code snippet I started from used the header parameter of `HttpSendRequest` to set the Content-Type. So that is the same as `HttpAddRequestHeaders`, too? Btw, if only one header is set with `HttpAddRequestHeaders` there is no reason to end the string with a CRLF, is there?

Comment: You can use `HttpAddRequestHeaders()` or `HttpSendRequest()` to specify extra headers as needed, but in both cases each individual header needs a CRLF at the end of it.

Comment: But not on the last header, or? Because I never have put a CRLF on that and it worked. (Thought about changing it to have a CRLF "but never change a running system")

Comment: All headers in `HttpAddRequestHeaders()` need to have CRLF. As for `HttpSendRequest()`, I'm not sure the format it expects, it is not documented. I would suggest just sticking with `HttpAddRequestHeaders()` and leave `lpszHeaders` NULL in `HttpSendRequest()`.